# Excel Lookup - two criteria using MATCH

Tags: excel

[image]

I have something that looks like the above. I need to return the column letter of a search value. Cells B5&C5 show the output.

The issue is that the columns will NOT remain constant; i.e. there could a NUM5, NUM6, or no NUM2, for example.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The question why do you want to find the column letter, are you going to use it later in another formula? It may be easier to skip this step and just get the value you want.

Comment: I do need to use it in another formula, however based on the way the file is setup, those changes would take a while

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use MATCH and SUBSTITUTE+ADDRESS, but you need a new row with concatenated values from first two rows. 
The formula in C6 is then

```
=SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,MATCH($B6&C$5,$A$3:$H$3,0),4),"1";"")
```

MATCH finds the column number and SUBSTITUTE+ADDRESS converts it to letter.

[image: solution]

Comment: Is there a way without a concatenation?